# Combinations from a multiset without repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am a bit confused with the following combinatorial problem, and perhaps somebody has stumbled upon a similar problem before. We have $k$ categories of objects (let's say that the objects are balls, and the categories are colors). So, we have $k$ colors, and we have $n_i$ balls of color $i$, for every $1 \leq i \leq k$, and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = N$$
My questions are:

1. In how many ways can I pick a subset of $m$ balls of different colors?
2. In how many ways can I pick a subset of $m$ balls of different colors, which contains a red ball?

The order of the balls within the subset is not important, and two balls of the same color are indistinguishable. Thus, what I want is *at most* one ball of each color. In the second question, one of the balls has to be red.

Comment: For question $(1)$, do you mean *exactly* one of each color? What about in $(2)$?

Comment: Are balls that have the same color distuingishable?

Comment: No, two balls of the same color are indistinguishable. I want at most one ball of each color.

Comment: For the first question, we to choose $m$ of the $k$ colors and one of the balls of each color we have selected.  For the second question, we need to choose one of the red balls, $m - 1$ of the other $k - 1$ colors, and one of the balls of each color we have selected.

Comment: so simple ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting $m$ categories out of $k$, so the answer on 1) is: $$\binom{k}{m}$$

You are selecting $m-1$ categories out of $k-1$, so the answer on 2) is: $$\binom{k-1}{m-1}$$

Comment: so simple ! thanks